# How do I change the keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I am thinking of developing an Android Keyboard which can replace the existing keyboard. As an example I might design a circular keyboard considering ergonomics factors and letter usage in the language.

My questions are,

1. Is it possible to change the keyboard given that the phone is not rooted?
2. If so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

there are several apps you can install that will be used as an alternative keyboard,if you then go into your keyboard settings you can change the default keyboard to whichever you like.

I use smart keyboard pro but the trial is also very good.

Comment: oh and no you don't need to be rooted :p

Comment: Any pointers to an article that describes how? I mean programatically?

Comment: not sure about articles but I learnt how from technobuffalo on youtube with this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuHmiG_YP6E

hope that helps :)